# h1 "hello world" text hiding behind of navigation bar how can i fix this

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap.

### this is my `navbar.html` code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
</nav>
```

### this is my `layout.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}
    {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    {% include "includes/navbar.html" %}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    {% block context %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

h1 "`hello world`" text hiding behind of navigation bar how can i fix this
note: navbar must be static in web site
THANKS

Comment: just remove the class `fixed-top`

Comment: when i remove ```fixed-top``` its not be static

Comment: `body { padding-top: 90px; }` (height of the navbar)

Comment: oh that was you mean with `static` :) Then your content needs a margin-top with the height of the navbar (to move the content below the navbar).

Comment: Please note that in CSS `position: static` is exactly the opposite of what you mean by "static" (which is `fixed`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed this problem i added br after the `body` tag 3 times

Answer (score 1):

add a `padding-top` in your main or section or

```
<div class="container" id="nameofsection">

<style>
  #nameofsection {
    padding-top:100px;
  }
</style>
```